# How to backup an Azure SQL database which contains encrypted stored procedures

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I have an Azure Powershell script that I have used to create a .bacpac file from an Azure SQL database.  It works fine on a basic test database (AdventureWorks), but now that I am trying to use it on a database which contains encrypted stored procedures I am getting the following error:

```
Error SQL71564: Error validating element [dbo].[encryptedSPROCName]: The element [dbo].[encryptedSPROCName] cannot be 
deployed as the script body is encrypted.
```

The stored procedures were created externally, so I do not have access to try to decrypt them.

The code block that I am using is:

```
$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
-DatabaseName $CopyDatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
-AdministratorLogin $Administratorlogin -AdministratorLoginPassword $AdministratorLoginPassword
```

Is there a way using Powershell to omit the encrypted stored procedures when executing the backup?

Comment: Does this help :https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131532/enable-tde-when-publishing-dacpac/131535

Answer (score 0):

Excluding Specific Object while export/import is not supported!!

However you can exclude certain object types using `sqlpackage.exe ExcludeObjectType=StoredProcedures`.

More options and info here - [Export Parameters and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh550080(vs.103).aspx#Anchor_3)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for being late to the party, but according to the documentation, ExcludeObjectType is not supported for the Export action.